# How to get sender's email address in gmail gadget?

Tags: email

I had written below custom extractor for getting senders's email address in gmail gadget. but i am not getting email address.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OpenCOBData id="extractorID">
    <ExtractorSpec platform="gmail" language="languageCode">
    <Search input_type="text">
      <Pattern input_fields="from_email">
       <![CDATA[(*.*)]]>
      </Pattern>
    </Search>
    <Response platform="gmail" format="cardgadget">

      <Output name="">{@__FROM_ADDRESS__}!</Output>
    </Response>
  </ExtractorSpec>
</OpenCOBData>
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong and what i have to do?